# need the ajax code for changing the button when a value is inserted to database in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Need the ajax code for changing the button when a value is inserted to database and it need to remain as changed until the value is removed from database

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btn_add_remove_cart').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var self = $(this);
       if (self.hasClass('add-cart')){ 
          // if it's add cart button, replace add-cart class by remove-cart and change label
          self.removeClass('add-cart').addClass('remove-cart').text('Remove');
       } else {
         // it's remove cart button, do the inverse
         self.removeClass('remove-cart').addClass('add-cart').text('Add to Cart');
       }
    });

});
```

Comment: any one knows the answer , pls help

Comment: where is your ajax code, what you have tried on server side(CI)?

Comment: i  need to remains it as remove until it is removed from the database